# Get data excluding time intervals in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, `Message` and `BlockUser`.

Table `Message`:

```
ID | Message | DateCreated 
1  | M1      | 2017-09-20 13:00:00
2  | M2      | 2017-09-20 14:00:00 
3  | M3      | 2017-09-21 13:00:00
4  | M3      | 2017-09-22 13:00:00
5  | M3      | 2017-09-23 13:00:00
6  | M3      | 2017-09-24 13:00:00
7  | M3      | 2017-09-25 13:00:00
```

Table `BlockUser`:

```
BlockStartDate       | BlockEndDate
2017-09-21 13:00:00  | 2017-09-22 13:00:00
2017-09-24 13:00:00  | 2017-09-24 14:00:00
```

Now I want rows from `Message` excluding those matching the intervals defined in `BlockUser`. So for my example the result should be:

```
ID | Message | DateCreated 
1  | M1      | 2017-09-20 13:00:00
2  | M2      | 2017-09-20 14:00:00 
5  | M3      | 2017-09-23 13:00:00
7  | M3      | 2017-09-25 13:00:00
```

I tried using this query but it didn't work:

```
WITH CTE AS (
         SELECT BlockStartDate,BlockEndDate FROM BlockUser
         )
SELECT * FROM Message 
WHERE DateCreated NOT BETWEEN 
(SELECT BlockStartDate FROM CTE) 
AND 
(SELECT BlockEndDate  FROM CTE)
```

It gives me this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic *anti-join* scenario. You want rows from one table excluding those matching another table.

In English, you could put the condition like this:

> Select every row from `Message` for which there is no matching row in `BlockUser`.

In SQL, one way of expressing the above is like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dbo.Message AS m
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      dbo.BlockUser AS bu
    WHERE
      m.DateCreated >= bu.BlockStartDate
      AND m.DateCreated < bu.BlockEndDate
  )
;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply try something like:

```
select m.*
from Message m
left join BlockUser b on m.datecreated between blockstartdate and blockenddate
where b.blockstartdate is null
```

Comment: Your answer works perfect too!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here what you want.

```
CREATE TABLE [Message](
ID INT, 
[Message] VARCHAR(10),
DateCreated DATETIME
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Message
        ( ID, Message, DateCreated )

VALUES
(1,'M1','2017-09-20 13:00:00'),
(2,'M2','2017-09-20 14:00:00'),
(3,'M3','2017-09-21 13:00:00'),
(4,'M3','2017-09-22 13:00:00'),
(5,'M3','2017-09-23 13:00:00'),
(6,'M3','2017-09-24 13:00:00'),
(7,'M3','2017-09-25 13:00:00')
GO
CREATE TABLE BlockUser(
StartDate DATETIME, 
EndDate DATETIME
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.BlockUser
        ( StartDate, EndDate )
VALUES  ( 
'2017-09-21 13:00:00',
'2017-09-22 13:00:00'),
('2017-09-24 13:00:00','2017-09-24 14:00:00')

SELECT Message.*
FROM dbo.Message
LEFT JOIN dbo.BlockUser ON DateCreated BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
WHERE startDate IS NULL
```