# Get Data for user excluding another user blocked with its time interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Two tables

```
Message



  ID | Message | FromUserId | ToUserId  | DateCreated
    1  | M1      |     A      |   B       | 2017-10-05 12:00:00
    2  | M2      |     A      |   B       | 2017-10-05 12:05:00
    3  | M3      |     B      |   A       | 2017-10-06 12:05:00
    4  | M4      |     B      |   A       | 2017-10-06 12:05:00
    5  | M5      |     A      |   B       | 2017-10-07 12:05:00
    6  | M6      |     A      |   B       | 2017-10-07 12:05:00
    7  | M7      |     B      |   A       | 2017-10-08 12:05:00
    8  | M8      |     B      |   A       | 2017-10-08 12:15:00
    9  | M9      |     B      |   A       | 2017-10-08 12:18:00
   10  | M9      |     B      |   A       | 2017-10-09 12:05:00

BlockedUsers

ID | FromUserId | BlockUserId | StartBlockDate       | EndBlockDate
1  |    A       |   B         | 2017-10-06 11:55:00  | 2017-10-07 11:55:00 
2  |    A       |   B         | 2017-10-08 10:05:00  | 2017-10-08 12:07:00 
3  |    A       |   B         | 2017-10-09 11:55:00  | NULL
```

Now when `B` tries to retrieve messages it gets whole messages of `Message` table

but when `A` retrieves messages, its result should be

```
Message

ID | Message | FromUserId | ToUserId  | DateCreated
1  | M1      |     A      |   B       | 2017-10-05 12:00:00
2  | M2      |     A      |   B       | 2017-10-05 12:05:00
5  | M5      |     A      |   B       | 2017-10-07 12:05:00
6  | M6      |     A      |   B       | 2017-10-07 12:05:00
8  | M8      |     B      |   A       | 2017-10-08 12:15:00
9  | M9      |     B      |   A       | 2017-10-08 12:18:00
```

I tried with below query

```
Declare @UserId int = A 
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dbo.Message AS m
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      dbo.BlockUser AS bu
    WHERE
      m.DateCreated >= bu.BlockStartDate
      AND m.DateCreated < bu.BlockEndDate
    and bu.FromUserId = @UserId
  )
;
```

I am stuck with the condition for user being blocked and another user.

I took reference of question:[get data excluding time intervals](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187010/get-data-excluding-time-intervals-in-another-table)

but could not figure

Comment: Not sure what it is you are asking for but `m.DateCreated < bu.BlockEndDate` will be null if bu.Blockdate is null. You can use coalesce like: `m.DateCreated < coalesce(bu.BlockEndDate, current_timestamp)` to handle open intervalls. Not sure what current_timestamp is named in SQL server

Comment: Okay @Lennart , let me try. But I am more or less stuck with the idea that A should not receive of B within the Blocked duration.

Comment: I request before giving down vote, please leave the comment for further reference.When someone is deep down stuck with an issue, then only one would ask question on SO and not just for entertainment.

Comment: I agree with @Hina Khuman, please give an explanation for down vote. That way the OP can improve the question, which everyone benefits from.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this would be to make the default value for the `EndBlockDate` be an arbitrary date far in the future instead of `NULL`. For example, if your `BlockedUsers` table was like this:

```
BlockedUsers

ID | FromUserId | BlockUserId | StartBlockDate       | EndBlockDate
1  |    A       |   B         | 2017-10-06 11:55:00  | 2017-10-07 11:55:00 
2  |    A       |   B         | 2017-10-08 10:05:00  | 2017-10-08 12:07:00 
3  |    A       |   B         | 2017-10-09 11:55:00  | 2150-12-31 23:59:59
```

Then your query above would correctly filter the information.

Comment: `m.DateCreated < coalesce(bu.BlockEndDate, current_timestamp)` works fine as commented by  [Lennart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39278/lennart). But I am stuck with the **condition of blocking of users by an user and there can be multiple**, here I have taken example as _A_ blocks _B_ , _A_ can block _C_ too. So totally message retrieve by _A_ should exclude duration when _B_ / _C_ are blocked